# How do you group MySQL results by type right after receiving them with php, but before encoding as json?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json

I am very new to php and sql and have been trying to figure out how to turn database results into pretty json format. My main issue is that I cannot group results by data type.

Below is the table, php code and results.

This is how the table looks.

```
+------+--------------+-------------+-----------+
|  id  |  type        | color       |  cuteness |
+------+--------------+-------------+-----------+
|  1   |  fluffy      | tricolor    |  10       |
|  2   |  shorthair   | brown       |  5        |
|  3   |  angry       | white       |  9        |
|  4   |  fluffy      | black       |  8        |
|  5   |  lazy        | white       |  10       |
|  6   |  fighter     | white       |  6        |
|  7   |  fluffy      | black       |  8        |
|  8   |  shorthair   | tricolor    |  9        |
|  9   |  fluffy      | transparent |  7        |
| 10   |  shorthair   | neon        |  10       |
+------+--------------+-------------+-----------+
```

PHP:

```
$query = "SELECT * from 'kittens' order by date DESC";  
$sendoff = execute($query, 1); 


if (num_of_rows($sendoff) > 0) {
    //number of rows 
    $conta = num_of_rows($sendoff);

    // kittens array
    $kittens_arr=array();
    $kittens_arr["kittens_data"]=array();

    //displaynumberofkittens
    $kittens_arr["count"]= $conta;

    while ($kittensori = fetch_array($sendoff)){  

        //used for future separations
        $kitten = $kittensori['category'];

        extract($kittensori);

        $kittenslist=array(
            "type" => $kitten_type,
            "name" => $kitte_nname,
            "color" => $kitten_color,
            "cuteness" => $cuteness,
        );
        array_push($kittens_arr["kittens_data"], $kittenslist);
    }
}
```

These are the results, which work, but I want to see if I could group the results by the type. So, if kitten is fluffy, then they should the grouped by that.

```
 {
 "kittens_data": [
  {
    "id": "1",
    "type": "fluffy",
    "color": "tricolor",
    "cuteness": "10",

  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "type": "shorthair",
    "color": "brown",
    "cuteness": "5",

  }
]
}
```

Something like this the json below. Is it even possible?

```
 {
 "kittens_data": [
  {
    "type": "fluffy",
    "box": [{
       "id": "1",
       "color": "tricolor",
       "cuteness": "10"
    },
    {
       "id": "7",
       "color": "black",
       "cuteness": "8"
    }]   
  },
  {
    "type": "shorthair",
    "box": [{
       "id": "2",
       "color": "brown",
       "cuteness": "5"
    },
    {
       "id": "8",
       "color": "tricolor",
       "cuteness": "9"
    }]   
  }
]
}
```

Any help, or pointing in the right direction will greatly help.

Answer (score 0):

you could say something like:

```
if(!isset($kittens_arr["kittens_data"][$kitten_type]){
    $kittens_arr["kittens_data"][$kitten_type][] = $kittenslist;
} else array_push($kittens_arr["kittens_data"][$kitten_type], $kittenslist);
```

There are probably other ways to do this but as a good introduction to multidimentional arrays this would be a good method to try

Answer (score 0):

Why bother generating JSON in php when your RDBMS (MySQL) has nice built-in capabilities for the same?

You should be able to get the output that you expect directly from database, mainly using functions [`JSON_OBJECT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-creation-functions.html#function_json-object) (that generates JSON objects) and [`JSON_ARRAYAGG()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg) (that aggregates JSON objects), available starting MySQL 5.7

To start with, here is a query that generates the JSON output that you are currently getting (apart from the surrounding `"kittens_data"` key):

```
select json_arrayagg(
  json_object(
    'id', id,
    'type', type,
    'color', color,
    'cuteness', cuteness
  )
) AS js 
from users;
```

The inner call to `JSON_OBJECT()` creates new objects from the input records, and the outer `JSON_ARRAYAGG()` function aggregates the whole JSON content in a single record with a single column called `js`.

It is quite easy to adapt the query to get the results that you expect. We need to first aggregate by `type`, then aggregate again in the outer query:

```
select json_arrayagg(js) js
from (
    select 
        json_object(
            'type', type,
            'box', json_arrayagg(json_object(id, 'id', color, 'color', cuteness, 'cuteness'))
        ) js
    from users
    group by type
) x;
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/g6MPFw8MQA4zfgo8bZoW8P/5)**.